# Extracting only the substring containing letters from a string containing digits strings and symbols

Tags: c#

I have a string that is like the following:

```
 string str = hello_16_0_2016;
```

What I want is to extract hello from the string. As in my program the string part can occur anywhere as it is autogenerated, so I cannot fix the position of my string.

For example: I can take the first five string from above and store it in a new variable.

But as occurring of letters is random and I want to extract only letters from the string above, so can someone guide me to the correct procedure to do this?

Comment: erm, `str.Split("_").First(s => s.All(char.IsLetter));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just use a simple regular expression to pull out only alphabetic characters, assuming you only need a-z?

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var str = "hello_16_0_2016";
var onlyLetters = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^a-zA-Z]", "");

// onlyLetters = "hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like this (uses Linq):

```
var str = "hello_16_0_2016";
var result = string.Concat(str.Where(char.IsLetter));
```

[Check it out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qaA2P5)

Or, if performance is a concern (because you have to do this on a tight loop, or have to convert hundreds of thousands of strings), it'd probably be faster to do:

```
var result = new string(str.Where(char.IsLetter).ToArray());
```

[Check it too](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0KxLTB)

Answer (score 0):

> But as occurring of letters is random and I want to extract only
>   letters from the string above, so can someone guide me to the correct
>   procedure to do this?

The following will extract the first text, without numbers anywhere in the string:

```
Console.WriteLine( Regex.Match("hello_16_0_2016", @"[A-Za-z]+").Value ); // "hello"
```